# Creating a function with a parameter that has a two tuple element

Tags: python

How do I create a function using fixed positions and speeds, using parameters:

1. impSpd: A two-element tuple where element 1 is the min # feet per
   second and element 2 is the max # for the imp (instead of the static and 7, respectively).
2. golemSpd: A two-element tuple identical to impSpd

Comment: Do you have a guess as to what the code to do this might look like? If so, I would recommend putting that in your question :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
def fun(impSpd, golemSpd):
    imp_min, imp_max = impSpd
    golem_min, golem_max = golemSpd
```

There's no good way to "unpack" or pattern match the arguments in the function definition. You can unpack them in the function body.

Comment: One of the things I miss from Python 2.   That you can't unpack tuples/lists in the arguments also severely limits the usefulness of lambdas.

Comment: Right! I had forgotten this was a feature in Python 2. Found some details on why it was removed; https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3113/